# A program wrote this data file - is it possible to tell what the likely language that program was written in?

Tags: programming-languages

Intellectual exercise.  I have a file, it contains structured data, some of which is straightforward text - like so (filename/extension is not helpful):

> DB1<80>^@¢^O^@^@^^^@^BX^A^@O¤<97>CALCULA~Calculatorÿÿf^Q^@^B]^A^A^K0ZERO
>   ÿÿÌ^O^@^B]^A^B^B1ONE ÿÿÌ^O^@^B]^A^C^B2TWO ÿÿÌ^Q^@^B]^A^D^D3THREE
>   ÿÿÌ^P^@^B]^A^E^C4FOUR ÿÿÌ^P^@^B]^A^F^C5FIVE
>   ÿÿÌ^U^@^BM^A^H^FmathPROBLEMÿÌÿ^W^@^BX^A^P#¤<85>¤+PAGEcloseÿÿf^O^@^B]^A^R^B6SIX
>   ÿÿÌ^Q^@^B]^A^S^D7SEVEN ÿÿÌ^Q^@^B]^A^T^D8EIGHT ÿÿÌ^P^@^B]^A^U^C9NINE
>   ÿÿÌ^P^@^B]^A^V^B10TEN ÿÿÌ^R^@^B^P^A^W^@¤t+ ¤uplus+^S^@^B]^A"^E11ELEVEN
>   ÿÿÌ^S^@^B]^A#^E12TWELVE ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^A$^G13THIRTEEN
>   ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^A%^G14FOURTEEN ÿÿÌ^T^@^B]^A&^F15FIFTEEN ÿÿÌ^S^@^B^P^A'^@¤t-
>   ¤uminus-^[^@^B^T^A(^H¤7¤x^[backspace.¤v%% ^T^@^B]^A2^F16SIXTEEN
>   ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^A3^G17SEVENTE~ ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^A4^G18EIGHTEEN
>   ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^A5^G19NINETEEN ÿÿÌ^S^@^B]^A6^E20TWENTY ÿÿÌ^T^@^B^P^A7^@¤t=
>   ¤uequals=*^@^BX^A8V¤<8c>(Math 26-50)SMRIGHTMore
>   numb's<99>Ìÿ^U^@^BX^A@^G¤:CLEARDI~
>   ÿÿf3^@^BX^AA/¤8¤x^[,hold,ctrl.^[backspace.DELTCHARDeleteÿÿf^U^@^B]^AB^G21TWENTYO~
>   ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^AC^G22TWENTTW~ ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^AD^G23TWENTTH~
>   ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^AE^G24TWENTFO~ ÿÿÌ^U^@^B]^AF^G25TWENTFI~
>   ÿÿÌ^T^@^B^P^AG^H¤t* ¤utimes* ^Y^@^B^P^AH^H¤t/ ¤udivided by/
>   ^P^@^BU^B^@^PandandÌÿÿ^_^@^BX^B^A^T¤<8c>(Geography)FLAG!USAÿø^?^P^@^BE^B^BAlbertaþüÔ(^@^BU^B^ChBritish
>   ColumbiaBritish ColumbþüÔ^Y^@^BU^B^D0ManitobaManitobþüÔ!^@^BU^B^EHNew
>   BrunswickNew BrunswþüÔ2^@^BU^B^FpNewfoundland and LabradorNewf &
>   LabradorþüÔ*^@^BU^B^GPNorthwest TerritoriesNW
>   TerritorþüÔ^W^@^B^L^B^H^GprovinceMANITOBA^W^@^BX^B^P#¤<85>¤+PAGEcloseÿÿf^U^@^B^L^B^Q^GCanadaCANADAF~^T^@^BE^B^RNova
>   ScotiaþüÔ^X^@^BU^B^S0NunavutNunavutþüÔ^X^@^BU^B^T0OntarioOntarioþüÔ^]^@^BE^B^UPrince
>   Edward
>   IslandþüÔ^V^@^BU^B^V(QuebecQuebecþüÔ$^@^BU^B^WhSaskatchewanSaskat-
>   chewanþüÔ^N^@^BE^B^XYukonþüÔ^T^@^BQ^B ^H¤ta ¤uuha
>   ÿÌÌ)^@^BQ^B0^@¤7¤x^[backspace.¤t. 
>   ¤<83>¤S¤<85>¤+¤<82>.ÿÿf&^@^B^\^B17Canadian
>   capitalCANADAF~capital^]^@^BU^B2PEdmontonEdmon^M

I'm interested to know how best to 'pretty print' the data - so I'd like to view the data in the structure it originally was. So my first thing to know here is:

A program wrote this file - is it possible to tell what the likely language that program was written in?

Comment: How does it start out with Calculator and work it's way through numbers to end up in Saskatchewan? This seems like interesting data...

Comment: this is nothing to do with a programming language, it's just reverse-engineering a binary format. Unless it's some language with a built-in serialization protocol which happens to match this ... but you're still reverse-engineering the format first.

Comment: It's affectively a wordlist, organised with on a couple of dimentions - by the way, I'm a bit confused why this has got so many downvotes... could anyone give me some information as to why?

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the starting 4 to 8 bytes, which are often used as a "magic number" to identify binary data files.  If you can identify the file format, you may be able to identify the software that created it.

Offhand, "DB1<80>" sounds like it should be a database of some sort.  However, if it's a proper DBMS system, you may be out of luck in tracking the language the application code was written in, since databases typically have bindings to all sorts of languages.

Comment: If it turned out to be a standard DBMS I'd be quite happy with that :) then I could use any language with the relevant library to process it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this data file in a program for something?

What platform?

looks like it could be a db, xml or plist containing strings.

i would try passing it into a data object seeing if you can convert that data object to xml and then dump the xml to the log to see if its more readable.

more specifics would be helpful.

Comment: I'd to be able to (as a basic case) simply pretty print it - it's designed for windows... (which is one of the problems I'm having, I'd like to be able to read it out on OSX